# Modifying global.asax on NuGet-Package Install

Tags: nuget, global-asax, nuget-package

I would like to create a NuGet package for the first time, and I need to add a line to the end of the Application_Start() function of global.asax when installing the package, and of course delete this line when the package being removed.

Answer (score 2):

There's an alternate method using a startup attribute that a lot of packages have adopted.

http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/02/appstart-folder-convention-for-nuget.html

https://bitbucket.org/davidebbo/webactivator/wiki/Home